# HtmlAgilityPack getting content in ChildNode using Class

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack, nodes

I have a basic HTML page. It is included omo area. Same class 8 diffrent content.

```
<div class="omo-page-wrapper">
    <div class="omo-part">
        <div class="omo-img">...</div>
        <div class="omo-info">
            <div class="r-logo">...</div>
            <div class="r-content font-hbold">
                <i>Content Area 1</i>
                <em>Content Area 2</em>
                <a href="/blabla">Href</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="omo-part">
        <div class="omo-img">...</div>
        <div class="omo-info">
            <div class="r-logo">...</div>
            <div class="r-content font-hbold">
                <i>Content Area 1</i>
                <em>Content Area 2</em>                
                <a href="/blabla2">Href2</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>
    <div class="omo-part">...</div>   
</div>
```

I want to get all contents (i, em, href) in all r-content font-hbold's classes. I'm used foreach and I got all nodes. But I didn't got ChildNodes..

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);

var allElementsWithClassTalkMedallion = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[contains(@class,'r-content font-hbold')]");

foreach (HtmlNode node in allElementsWithClassTalkMedallion)
{
    dataTable.Rows.Add("i", "em", "href"); //??
}

return promotions;
```

8 (or more) same class area, 3 childnodes. How can I get all i, em, href contents? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way, you can use `SelectSingleNode()` to get specific node one at a time from each `node` variable :

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in allElementsWithClassTalkMedallion)
{
    var i = node.SelectSingleNode("i").InnerText.Trim();
    var em = node.SelectSingleNode("em").InnerText.Trim();
    var href = node.SelectSingleNode("href").InnerText.Trim();
    dataTable.Rows.Add(i, em, href);
}
```